# Usage monitoring from whitelisted IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to setup a shared processing service that uses a load balancer and several EC2 instances to process incoming requests using a custom .NET application. My issue is that I need to be able to bill based on usage. Only white-listed IPs will be able to call the application, but each IP only gets a set number of calls before each call is a billable event.

Since the AWS documentation for the ELB states "We recommend that you use access logs to understand the nature of the requests, not as a complete accounting of all requests", I do not feel the Access Logs on the ELB is what I'm looking for.

The question I have is how to best manage this so that the accounting team has an easy report each month that says how many calls each client made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can use Access logs and since access logs will be written to S3, you can query each IP with Athena by using standard SQL. You can analyze your logs and extract reports.

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-analyze-access-logs/

Comment: My concern with this is that AWS states they do not recommend using access logs for a complete accounting of all requests. That makes me wary of using that method.

Comment: Have you considered using AWS WAF? It's also highly monitorable, you can create custom rules, whitelist IPs etc.

https://aws.amazon.com/waf/getting-started/